# Im trying to print user uid after login anonymously but it's empty/nothing printed

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

im trying to get the user information after sign in anonymously and print it to the console but i got nothing even nothing printed on the screen.

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // sign in anon
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User user = result.user!;
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

```
body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 50.0),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Sign in anon"),
          onPressed: () async {
            dynamic result = await _auth.signInAnon();
            if (result == null) {
              print('error signing in');
            } else {
              print('signed in');
              print(result);
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Since you print both when `result == null` and when it isn't, I'd expect one of those `print` statements to execute. If it doesn't, I'd expect `print(e.toString())` to be executed. If that doesn't happen either, it seems like the authentication doesn't complete (e.g. because there is no network connect?)

Comment: Exactly, there was nothing on the console. After a moment im notice something telling like "header is null....." i googled it and it was my internet connection on the emulator didn't have the internet. So it solved now

Comment: Good to hear Foxter.  --- I voted to close your question as ephemeral.